# No matching constructor for initalization of 'ostream_iterator<int>'

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, iostream

for the code, why error, osteam_iterator is a template class ,why no matching constructor for initalization of 'ostream_iterator', please give a help , thank you.
define ostream_iterator
template  >
class _LIBCPP_VISIBLE ostream_iterator

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> sentence1;
    sentence1.reserve(5);// 设置每次分配内存的大小

    sentence1.push_back(1);
    sentence1.push_back(2);
    sentence1.push_back(3);
    sentence1.push_back(4);
    sentence1.push_back(5);

    int c = 5;

    copy(sentence1.begin(), sentence1.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, 1));
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator

Comment: what's mean, this link is current page.

Comment: Oops, I fixed that now ;)

Comment: cause no constructor that take an int as second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ostream_iterator class definition looks like:

```
template< class T,
  class CharT = char,
  class Traits = std::char_traits<charT>>
class ostream_iterator /*...*/
```

whereas the respective constructor is declared as:

```
ostream_iterator(ostream_type& buffer, const CharT* delim)
```

Since the second template argument of an `ostream_iterator` is required to be of character type you cannot simply replace it with int.

If you ommit the second template parameter you can plug in a string literal of type `char const *`:

```
std::copy(sentence1.begin(), sentence1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
```

If C++11 is available to you then

```
int c = 5;
for ( auto v : sentence1 ) std::cout << v << c;
```

is another way of doing what you deserve and it might be suitable, too. 
The advantage is, that `operator<<` is more flexible than an argument of type "pointer to char type".

Answer (score 5):

[ostream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/ostream_iterator) constructor takes `const CharT* delim` as second parameter:

> ostream_iterator(ostream_type& stream, const CharT* delim) (1)
>
> ostream_iterator(ostream_type& stream) (2)

To make your code work, you need to pass in a string:

```
std::copy(sentence1.begin(), sentence1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "1"));
//                                                                             ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::ostream_iterator` takes a string as the second parameter to the constructor.  This is the string that will be output after each integer in the sequence.